# Copy files from docker to host when mounting

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a volume setup like this:

```
volumes:
  - type: bind
    source: //c//Docker/themes
    target: /var/www/html/wp-content/themes
```

It works but when I create this mount it deletes all the files that were on the docker in specified path.

Is there an option or way to preserve those files and copy them to the host?

Comment: Is the host directory initially empty?

Answer (score 1):

Mounting does not delete the data that exist on the destination path, it hides it until you remove the mount point you will find the old data still exist. Think of it as the old data exist beneath the new volume that you have mounted

For example if you have `wp-content/uploads/` on the main hard disk and for some reason you decided to have a separate disk for the upload. If you mounted the new hard disk directly which points to the upload path, it will hide the old files but wont delete them which is why you need to migrate the data first before mounting.

So I usually copy the content from the container first - if needed - to the host then i do the mounting part. So you can use this command first (I assume you are on windows  - because of `//c` part - as I am not a windows user so you might need to change the path as needed):

```
docker cp mycontainer:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes //c//Docker/themes
```

After this you can mount the host directory which will contain everything. but make sure you don't have similar directories on the host before copying to avoid overriding the data.

Comment: I use a docker-compose file to bring containers up.  Any way I can do it without manually removing the volumes from compose file each time it is set up?

Comment: @Guerrilla, are we talking about the original wordpress themes ? if thats the case so what about getting them from the same wordpress version that you are using and saving it locally ?