# how to let dockerized shinyapp load data from local drive (on host machine)

Tags: r, docker, shiny, shiny-server, shinyproxy

I made a simple shinyapp.  It reads a dataset called `mydata.rds` from a folder on my local drive.

The data on my local drive is *updating everyday*.

The app runs perfectly as a standalone app on my rstudio. Below is the `global.r` file.

```
## global.r
 library(shiny)
 data = readRDS("/path_to_local_folder/mydata.rds")
```

Then I build a shinyapp docker image successfully.

I ran the docker image like below. It did not work.

```
docker run --rm  -p 80:80 myshinyapp
```

So I tried to mount the local folder and ran the docker image like this"

```
docker run --rm -v /path_to_local_folder/:/srv/shiny-server/  -p 80:80 myshinyapp
```

what I got on my `localhost` is:

```
Index of/

 mydata.rds
```

Does anyone know why that happens in both cases above? What I did wrong when mounting volume?

*what I'm trying to do is to connect my dockerized shinyapp to some local data folder which is undating everyday. What I want is when docker start a container, it loads data from data folder on host machine. (I'm actually trying to host my app on a host machine with shinyproxy server).*

Instruction on how I can achieve that is much appreciated.

Note: when I simply pack my app and data everything into docker image and run it. The app works fine. There does not seem to be any problem with my app.

Comment: Didn't see a real question here, what's the error?

Comment: Could it be that you are reading your RDS file from an *absolute* path, pointing to the physical location, rather than reading from a relative path? From within your dockerized shinyapp, the path would be `/srv/shiny-server/mydata.rds`.

Comment: @MrGrumble    I editted the question to explain better.

Comment: @MrGrumble  I did not copy the data folder. Because I assume it will make the container big, not efficient way to do? I want the app be a multiuser scalable one on a host machine with shinyproxy server.  Just want the app reach a data folder on host machine. Data is changing everyday.  Your detailed answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you mount the local folder to the container files and folders in `/srv/shiny-server/` will be hidden until you remove the mount.

So you have not to mount the volume and copy files after starting the container by `docker cp` command or modify Dockerfile of your shinyapp image to copy the file you need from host to the image wile building so you will find it after starting the container.

Or follow instruction [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56893439/copy-files-from-docker-to-host-when-mounting/56894212#56894212).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.  Sorry, I edited the question so that it is more clearly explained. My data folder is updating everyday. Please take another look at it.  If I modify the Dockerfile, will that reflect the change when a container is started?  I guess if I do that, the container get big because it loads the data folder.  Probably not efficient way to do that?  Thanks. @Ahmed Arafa

Comment: I faced this issue in my project and solve it by executing bash script copy files to the directory after mounting the volume, check here:
https://github.com/Ahmed-M-Arafa/nginx-php-mariadb-alpine